# Как в функцию передать массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

суть проблемы вот в чем: Я хочу вынести массив в глобальную видимость, чтобы выбранные даты туда записывать. Не пойму как это сделать. Массив вне функции не видно внутри функции. Вообще мне нужно чтобы выбрав даты и нажав на добавить период, все что я выберу до этого, было disabled, для этого я этот массив и делаю

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var disabledTarifDates = ['2018-7-20', '2018-7-21', '2018-7-22', '2018-7-23'];

    $('.add-tarif__tabs li').each(function () {
        var tab_id = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        var period = $(tab_id);
        var start = period.find('.startDate');
        var end = period.find('.endDate');
        startCalendar(start, end);
    });

    var addTarifCount = 0;

    $('.add-tarif__add-period').on('click', function () {

        addTarifCount += 1;

        var startId = "start_" + addTarifCount;
        var endId = "end_" + addTarifCount;

      $(this).before('<div class="add-tarif__box"><h4 class="title">Период действия</h4><div class="reservation-calendar add-tarif__period-date line">' +
            '<div class="reservation-calendar__item"><input class="start startDate" type="text" readonly="" id="'+startId+'">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="reservation-calendar__item"><input class="start endDate" type="text" readonly="" id="'+endId+'">' +
            '</div></div>' +
            '</div></div>');

        startCalendar($("#"+startId), $("#"+endId));

    });

    // var disabledTarifDates = ['2018-7-20', '2018-7-21', '2018-7-22', '2018-7-23']; ERROR

    function startCalendar(start, end) {
        
        

        var $startTarifDate = start;
        var $endTarifDate = end;

        $startTarifDate.datepicker({
            inline: false,
            range: true,
            toggleSelected: true,
            minDate: new Date(),
            multipleDatesSeparator: ",",
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
            onSelect: function (fd, date) {
                if(date){
                    var arrDate = fd.split(",");
                    $startTarifDate.val(arrDate[0]);
                    $endTarifDate.val(arrDate[1]);
                    if(arrDate[1]){
                        $('.datepicker').css("left", "-100000px");
                        $startTarifDate.blur();
                    }
                    $endTarifDate.on('click', function () {
                        $startTarifDate.datepicker().val(arrDate[0]).data('datepicker').show();
                    });
                }
            },
            onRenderCell: function(date, cellType) {
                console.log(disabledTarifDates);
                var formatteds = getFormattedDate(date);
                if (cellType == 'day') {
                    var returnDay = {
                        disabled: false
                    };
                    console.log(date);
                    var selectedTarifDate = disabledTarifDates.filter(function(date){
                        return date == formatteds;
                    }).length;
                    console.log(selectedTarifDate);
                    if( selectedTarifDate > 0){
                        returnDay = {
                            disabled: true
                        };
                    }
                    return returnDay;
                }
            }
        });

    }
  
  function getFormattedDate(date) {
        var year = date.getFullYear(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            date = date.getDate();
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + date;
    }
  
  
});
```

```css
.reservation-calendar__item{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
.add-tarif__box {
  text-align: center;
}
.add-tarif__box button {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<div class="add-tarif">
  <div class="add-tarif__category vertical tabs" data-tabs="" id="example-tabs" role="tablist" data-e="zvezbi-e">
    <ul class="add-tarif__tabs">
      <li class="tabs-title is-active" role="presentation">
        <a href="#panel1" aria-selected="true" role="tab" aria-controls="panel1" id="panel1-label" tabindex="0">Категория "Люкс"</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="add-tarif__period" data-tabs-content="example-tabs">
    <div class="add-tarif__period-item tabs-panel is-active" id="panel1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="panel1-label">
      <div class="add-tarif__box">
        <h4 class="title">Период действия</h4>
        <div class="reservation-calendar add-tarif__period-date line">
          <div class="reservation-calendar__item">
            <input class="start startDate" type="text" readonly="" id="startPeriod1">
          </div>
          <div class="reservation-calendar__item">
            <input class="start endDate" type="text" readonly="" id="endPeriod1">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="add-tarif__add-period" type="button">Добавить период</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Чтобы переменная попала в глобальную область видимости из тела функции - объявите ее без использования ключевого слова (var, let, const)

Comment: Проблема была в том, что я ссылался на массив раньше, чем его объявлял

Comment: Области видимости определяются синтаксически. Просто объявите массив во внешнем контексте по отношению ко всем функциям, использующим его.

Comment: @Дмытрык, за такое бить по рукам нужно. Неявное определение переменной в глобальной области видимости - плохо. Хотите объявить? Делайте это явно, через `window.somevar`